# How to add required validation for file field ( input type="file" ) using parsley js?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, parsley.js, parsley

While doing validation of form fields, I can validating all fields using required attibutes parsley.js. Except the file field. I couldn't able to validate file upload field. When i check the code using developer tool (inspect element) in Firefox there is no classes added for the validation at filed field. Remaining text field, Select fields are having the additional parsley classes.

**My HTML Code:**

```
<input type="file" id="uploadDox" name="filename" class="form-control" required>
```

**Parsley form submit JS code:**

```
var form_update = $form_update.parsley();
  $btn_form_update.on('click', function(evt) {
     evt.preventDefault();
    if ( form_update.validate() ) {
      loading( $(this), true );
      $form_update_trainingDocs.submit();
    }
  });
```

what mistake i did there. How can i validate the file field using parsley.js.
Please give your suggestion on this.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you make the simple effort of providing a minimal working example (like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/marcandre/f1d4014t/)), you would easily see that `parsley` handles `required` for files just fine.

So the error is in your code / HTML. I imagine that your issue is calling `validate()` instead of `validate(true)`, the former does not enforce requiredness.

Comment: @Marc-Anre Lafortune Thx for your answer. I tried this. but no luck. If i removed the line // evt.preventDefault(); from JS code. Then the parsley validation is working for file field. I want to know why when i am using evt.preventDefault(). It doesn't validate. This problem only for file field not other fields like text, select.

Comment: When I update the latest version of Parsley.js The file field validation is working fine.. :-)